# Drawing simulator - Tracking mouse movement

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop

I was wondering what would be the logic behind coding a drawing simulator like the one on this website: https://www.mdbg.net/chindict/chindict.php?page=chardict&cdcanoce=0&cdqchi=
The paintbrush tool when you click it, once you start drawing strokes that a similar to what a character is, it will automatically bring out a list of characters that leads toward what you are drawing. Once you are finished, the correct character will show up.
To my idea, I think that a set of coordinates are set already and once the mouse coordinates passes through these points, then from there it will detect and provide all the possibilities and narrows it even further. I think this is very complex but what would be the right path/correct way to go about programming this concept?